# calling setState multiple times not working properly

Tags: reactjs

So I want to show spinner on my component every time it making API calls, what my function did is something like this:

```
setShowSpinner(true)
makeAPICall()
setShowSpinner(false)
```

It didnt work, only the last `setShowSpinner` was firing, and the spinner never showed up.
I've heard that setState may be asynchronous, so I've tried something like:

```
setShowSpinner(true)
makeAPICall()
setShowSpinner(prevState => !prevState)
```

It didn't work either. Only when I wrap the second `setShowSpinner` inside `setTimeout` it works,

```
setShowSpinner(true)
makeAPICall()
setTimeout(() => setShowSpinner(false) ,someDelay)
```

but I think it is more of a hacky way instead of a good practice. Is there another way to improve it ?

Comment: What is `makeAPICall()`, can you give more context? Maybe you can show the component?

Comment: in case `makeAPICall` is async, you might want to wait until it is resolved, e.g. `makeAPICall().then(setShowSpinner(false))`

Comment: You are not waiting for the API call. line 2 and 3 are executed right after the other. there is no waiting

Comment: if ```makeAPICall``` is async then you've to use ```async await``` or ```Promises```. Once the request is complete then you've to change the state

Answer (score 0):

you need to solve this problem like this:

```
setShowSpinner(true)
makeAPICall().then(res => {
   setShowSpinner(false)
}).catch(err => {
   console.log(err)
   setShowSpinner(false)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice would to do something like this:

```js
function fetchData() {
    setShowSpinner(true);
    makeAPICall()
     .then((result) => {
        // do what ever with the result
    })
     .catch((err) => {
        // do what ever with the result
    })
     .finally(() => {
        setShowSpinner(false))
    }
}
```

Finally makes sure that even though Promise was rejected, you won't enter infinite loading state. Read more [in MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Promise way like already mentioned in answers. I just wanted to give you another way of doing it. Probably you must be using a wrapper function for this loading spinner and API call.
Let's check this way out.

```
const handleAPICall = async (args) => {
  setShowSpinner(true)
  // This will wait until your API call is pending or 
  // your Promise is resolved
  await makeAPICall()
  setShowSpinner(false)
}
```

You can still use `.then()` approach. It's upto you what you feel is good for you.